# OnTriggerEnter how to work with other objects and not on the object on which the script is located

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good afternoon, I have a script that should read the hit of the ball in two different objects that I set as

```
public GameObject LeftHitTrigger;
public GameObject RightHitTrigger;
```

how to write OnTriggerEnter so that it works with one object and with another

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (LeftHitTrigger.colission, collision.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
        {
            AiCount++;
            Debug.Log(AiCount);
            AiCountText.text = AiCount.ToString();
        }
        
        if (RightHitTrigger.colission, collision.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
        {
            AvatarCount++;
            Debug.Log(AvatarCount);
            AvatarCountText.text = AvatarCount.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I tried this but it doesn't work and i get errors after "LeftHitTrigger.colission," and "RightHitTrigger.colission," in brackets.

Comment: Correct. The collision details are in the variable defined in the method header. You can’t just add items in the condition like that.

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]